# Where in Poland and when in 1986 did stuntman Ian B. Jamieson perform?

Tags: poland, date

I've these 3 old pictures of mine:

[image: Ian Bruce Jamieson, To jest Bomba]
[image: Ian Bruce Jamieson, Tego w Europie jeszcze nie bylo]
[image: Ian Bruce Jamieson, Auto Moto Rodeo]

So my question is:

Where and when stuntman did Ian Bruce Jamieson perform in Poland?

Some known details:

The pictures are from around 1986 taken in Szczecin, Poland. On the picture you can also find a reference to [Auto Moto Rodeo](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_Moto_Rodeo) (Polish automotive revue). I think there is also a book by Jameison, *Kaskader*, which supposedly describes this event (but I don't have it). It seems there aren't many details in Wikipedia. This could be potentially on the Sea Days in Szczecin on 21 june 1986, but it's just a guess ([link](http://smw.ocalicodzapomnienia.eu/index.php?o=pokaz&katid=14&pkatid=26&jid=1&postid=613)). Potential places are near Odra river, King Chrobry's Embankment.

Based on the above, is there any way of historically confirming the place and the date?

Comment: http://ianbjamieson.com/kaskader.html

Comment: There's a deleted answer (without any supporting info) that he performed in Szczecin on June 15 1986.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After performing some social media searches, I realized that Mr. Jamieson has a Facebook page. I have started a short dialog with him during which he has responded thusly:

> Me: "When did you perform in Poland in the 70's?"
>
> Ian: "Hi Chris, It all happened in 1986"
>
> Me: "By the way, the reason I asked was to answer a question asked here: [Where and when stuntman Ian B. Jamieson performed in Poland in '80?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/16805/where-and-when-stuntman-ian-b-jamieson-performed-in-poland-in-80)"
>
> Ian: "Chris, I performed all over Poland. Are you one of the boys in the photo? Warsaw, Konin, Poznan, leszno, szczecin, bydgosh, koszalin, katowice, Raciborz"

Comment: Thanks. If possible, I'd like to know the exact date and place in Szczecin.

Comment: If you go to his [website](http://ianbjamieson.com/), there is a contact on it and he is very responsive.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried already. I've asked him the same question in the past via e-mail, but I've been given only year and city as well and on further e-mails I didn't get any response about the date.